# PowerShell alias - No restrictions on name

Tags: powershell

I have written a simple `SetDifference` function, by using the `Compare-Object` function:

```
Function SetDifference {
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$ReferenceObject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$DifferenceObject
    )

    Compare-Object $ReferenceObject $DifferenceObject | 
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.InputObject }
}
```

I've noticed that ANY alias can be used without PowerShell complaining:

```
Set-Alias '\' 'SetDifference'
Set-Alias '.' 'SetDifference'
Set-Alias '+' 'SetDifference'
```

Shouldn't there be restrictions on what the alias name can be - to stop you from using symbols that are already part of PowerShell syntax?

Comment: What the point of such restriction?

Comment: To stop you from using symbols that are part of the PowerShell language

Comment: Why do you need someone to stop you. Just do not do that. Aliases can not redefine meaning of symbols anyway, them only affect command name resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You should get an error, when using i.e. the '+'.

See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849938.aspx), you should follow this: "You can use any alphanumeric characters in an alias, but the first character cannot be a number."

Also resuing an already defined alias will throw an error.